# How do I build a file list for scons MSVSProject builder function?

Tags: scons

I'm currently trying something like -

```
projects = envsrc.MSVSProject(target = 'none' + env['MSVSPROJECTSUFFIX'],
srcs = Glob("src/*.cpp"),
incs = Glob("src/*.hpp"),
buildtarget = exe,
variant = 'Release')
```

But I get the error that srcs must be a string or list of strings, what is the right way to this? src is a folder within root dir that contains headers and cpp files, sconscript is in the root dir

Comment: The Glob() function always operates relative to the current SConscript file, so do those directories exist relative to the current SConscript?

Comment: Yes, they do exist. Even a simple single line test fails.

Comment: Can you show the basic dir structure, including where the SConsctruct/Sconscript files are.

Comment: Sconstruct and Sconscript are in the root dir, then I have a src dir that has a few src and headers along with the above folder struture like shown in the original post. But the weird thing is I can't even get a single glob to work like so -                                            projects = env.MSVSProject(target = 'none' + env['MSVSPROJECTSUFFIX'],
 srcs = Glob("src/*.cpp"),
 incs = Glob("src/*.hpp"),
 buildtarget = exe,
 variant = 'Release')

Comment: Is there any way to echo the Sources path?

Comment: It would be better to add this info to the original question, since its really hard to read in a comment. To print the Sources in Python, just do either "print Sources", or even better "print Sources.join(', ')"

Comment: it says invalid syntax, I should mention I'm calling scons from the command line

Comment: Ya I figured out the invalid syntax, and the answer to your question and posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is when I was trying to see why the print statement I suggested in the comments didnt work.

First of all, an efficient way in Python to print all the strings in a list of strings is like this:

```
', '.join(Sources)
```

The part in the quotes `', '` is the separator between elements in the list of strings.

I realized the problem with the following SConstruct excerpt:

```
sources = (Glob('src/dir1/*.cc')
+Glob('src/dir2/*.cc')
+Glob('src/dir3/*.cc'))

print sources
print ', '.join(sources)
```

Which gives this output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
[<SCons.Node.FS.File object at 0x122e4d0>, <SCons.Node.FS.File object at 0x122e710>, <SCons.Node.FS.File object at 0x122e950>]
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, File found:
  File "/home/notroot/projects/sandbox/SconsGlob/SConstruct", line 10:
    print ', '.join(sources)
```

That's when I remembered that the SCons Glob() function returns a list of Nodes (Files), not a list of strings. According to the [SCons man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) (search for 'glob(' ) the usage is as follows:

```
Glob(pattern, [ondisk, source, strings])
```

And the strings argument does the following:

> The strings argument may be set to True (or any equivalent value) to
>   have the Glob() function return strings, not Nodes, that represent the
>   matched files or directories...

The MSVSProject() builder is expecting a list of strings, not Nodes. So, it works as you are expecting if you do the following:

```
sources = (Glob('src/dir1/*.cc', strings=True)
+Glob('src/dir2/*.cc', strings=True)
+Glob('src/dir3/*.cc', strings=True))

print ', '.join(sources)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
src/dir1/main.cc, src/dir2/func2.cc, src/dir3/func3.cc
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

Comment: It outputted a .sln and a .vcxproj file but they won't open. Are there any other parameters I need to set to get a working sln file?

Comment: @drwbns, sorry I dont use MSVS, so I dont know.

Comment: Actually it did work, I was opening a created dummy file, the real files are placed in the root dir :)